# Elo points after game completion

Tags: rating, elo

When playing an opponent and winning, are the points taken from the opponent's Elo at the beginning of the game or end of the game? For example, I may play someone who begins at 1900 and is at 1600 when the game ends as they have played other players at the same time.

Comment: In normal (over the board) chess, that can't happen, so you're probably talking about some website. Rules differ between sites, so we need to know which (and what kind of game).

Comment: Hi, its ChessByPost on iPhone

Comment: @mister please accept an answer or specify what additional info you would like to have. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the ratings used for the calculation are the ratings you and your opponent had at the beginning of your game. The change of rating is applied on your ratings after your game is done. For example

> Scenario: when the game starts, your rating is 2000 and the
>   opponent's is 1900. When the game finishes, your rating is 2150 (due
>   to other finished games) while your opponent's is 2100. Then, under my
>   assumption above, the following happens (if you won the game)
>
> Your New Rating = 2150 + 2000_wins_against_1900
>
> Opponent New Rating = 2100 - 1900_loses_against_2000

Comment: Your best bet is still to contact the ChessByPost support and ask how they calculate the ratings. Cheers.